# Share image with gmail application doesn't work

Tags: android, image, gmail, share

I Have sharing image problem with the Gmail Application.
This is my code.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);     
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,  getString(R.string.mail_subject)); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  getString(R.string.mail_body)); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, getString(R.string.facebook_share_text));


    //Download the image first
    String location=downloadImage(true);
    File root=android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    Log.e("send from where:","file:///"+root.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+location);

    //Add attachment
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///"+root.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+location));

    emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.share_by)));
```

Default email app is Working great, Facebook Share is working great, Gmail App seams to work but the attachment is not send, although is displayed as attachment.

Here are the screen shots.
[image: All share options]
[image: Email is send but without attachment, although the attachment is displayed here]
[image: Facebook share is perfect]

So please help.

Answer (score 3):

```
String location=downloadImage(true);
File root=android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
Log.e("send from where:","file:///"+root.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+location);

//Add attachment
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///"+
root.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+location));
 // replace "Uri.parse" with Uri.fromFile(new File("file:///"+
root.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+location))
emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.share_by)));
```

This thing actually worked for me. Same thing occurs to me, when I sent the `Uri.parse`. You can see that the size of the attachment will show 0 kb. But when I change it, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Share image working on facebook,whatsapp,gmail,bluetooth and messages also**

```
            Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageUri);
            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share with.."));
```